# I want to replace the text to the end of the line (right) only , without replacing the others text starting the same name to the left part

Tags: vba, notepad++, microsoft-excel-2013

I want to replace the text to the end of the line (right) only , without replacing the others text starting the same name to the left part.
Consider this line:
**Replace1 in the text *Replace1.***

I want to replace the Replace1(formated with italic) that is to the end of the line with some other text without changing the Replace1 that is beginning at the start of the line.
I usually want to do this in notepad++ or excel but if any other programming languages that does this job , kindly mention it ,would be
Highly Appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the format of your data, you could possibly accomplish this in excel with the left() and len(), perhaps combining with the find() command, and adding your new characters within that function.

I was able to change your data to "Replace1 in the text Replace2" with this command: `=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)&2`

Here's some more info on removing characters from the beginning or end of cells.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Remove-characters-from-text-49ec57f9-3d5a-44b2-82da-50dded6e4a68

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression may be the simplest way to do this.

The search expression would look like this...

```
Replace1$
```

The $ will tell it to match the line ending, so it won't effect the word at the start of the line.